# Is it possible to provide a list of custom stopwords to RTextTools package?

Tags: r, text-mining, stop-words, tm

With the tm package I'm able to do it like this:

```
c0 <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
c0 <- tm_map(c0, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),mystopwords))
```

`mystopwords` being a vector of the additional stopwords I want to remove.

But I can't find an equivalent way to do it using the RTextTools package. For example:

```
dtm <- create_matrix(text,language="english",
             removePunctuation=T,
             stripWhitespace=T,
             toLower=T,
             removeStopwords=T, #no clear way to specify a custom list here!
             stemWords=T)
```

Is it possible to do this? I really like the `RTextTools` interface and it would be a pity to have to move back to `tm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three (or possible even more) solutions to your problem:

First, use the `tm` package only for removing words. Both packages deal with the same objects, therefore you can use `tm` just for removing words and than the `RTextTools` package. Even when you look inside the function `create_matrix` it uses `tm` functions.

Second, modify the `create_matrix` function. For example add an input parameter like `own_stopwords=NULL` and add the following lines:

```
# existing line
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(trainingColumn), 
                     readerControl = list(language = language))
# after that add this new line
if(!is.null(own_stopwords)) corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, 
                                          words=as.character(own_stopwords))
```

Third, write your own function, something like this:

```
# excluder function
remove_my_stopwords<-function(own_stw, dtm){
  ind<-sapply(own_stw, function(x, words){
    if(any(x==words)) return(which(x==words)) else return(NA)
  }, words=colnames(dtm))
  return(dtm[ ,-c(na.omit(ind))])  
}
```

let´s have a look if it works:

```
# let´s test it
data(NYTimes)
data <- NYTimes[sample(1:3100, size=10,replace=FALSE),]
matrix <- create_matrix(cbind(data["Title"], data["Subject"]))

head(colnames(matrix), 5)
# [1] "109"         "200th"       "abc"         "amid"        "anniversary"


# let´s consider some "own" stopwords as words above
ostw <- head(colnames(matrix), 5)

matrix2<-remove_my_stopwords(own_stw=ostw, dtm=matrix)

# check if they are still there
sapply(ostw, function(x, words) any(x==words), words=colnames(matrix2))
#109       200th         abc        amid anniversary 
#FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Although, given that the RTextTools package loses some of the functionality (or loses an easy implementation), would you recommend using it all? (Over sticking with the tm package)

Comment: I think it depends on the since of your matrix and stop word vector. In general I would do solution three, but if the matrix and the stop word vector are too big you can get memory problems. Than I would do solution 2, add the lines, name it eg. `create_matrix2`, but it on a file and source it. Than you can use `create_matrix2` in the same way as the old function but with the new feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your stop words in the same list. For example:

```
c0 <- tm_map(c0, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"),"mystopwords"))
```